# External Javascript isn't updating account balance

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, console, external-api

I have a simple smart contract that is supposed to record input strings on the blockchain using events:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract Recorder{
  event Record(
    address _from,
    string _message,
    uint _cash
  );

  function record(string message) public payable {
    Record(msg.sender,message,msg.value);
  }

  function () public payable {} 
}
```

I have deployed it on my testrpc network and it works fine. I have this external javascript code that I execute view truffle console:

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
const Recorder = artifacts.require('Recorder');
//const artifacts = require('./build/contracts/Recorder.json');


recorder = Recorder.at(Recorder.address);


recorder.record.sendTransaction("123",{from: web3.eth.accounts[0],value: 70}).then(console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(Recorder.address)));

console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(Recorder.address));

}
```

It works fine, but the account balance doesn't update in the script. The console.log portion shows a balance of 0 at the address.

If I console.log the account balance in the truffle console after running this external script it shows the correct balance.

If I run the external script again it shows a non-updated account balance. If I run the script once it shows a balance of 0. The second time I run the console.log portion only shows 70, etc.

The truffle console is always up to date, but the external script is always one run behind. It isn't a big issue, I just want to expand my understanding of what is going on in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to execute the log after the transaction was mined

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
  const Recorder = artifacts.require('Recorder');
  const recorder = Recorder.at(Recorder.address);

  recorder.record("123",{from: web3.eth.accounts[0],value: 70}).then(function () {
    console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(Recorder.address)); 
  });
}
```

In truffle you have this posibilities

- `myContract.method(params)` will wait until the transaction was added to the blockchain.
- `myContract.method.sendTransaction(params)` will return immediately with the transaction hash without waiting.
- `myContract.method.call(params)` will execute the function no changes will be done to the contract (ie like it was a getter).
- `myContract.method.estimateGas(params)` will estimate how much gas will consume.

Comment: Thank You so much. This makes a lot of sense and fixed my problem.